# Why it is taking individual number as a separate value

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

```js
for (var i in req.body.guides) {
 db.query('INSERT INTO guide_categories(pin_id,guide_id) values($1,$2)', [req.body.guides[i], pin.rows[0]._id], function(err, pin) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  console.log("success");
  });
}
```

I am trying to insert array values from postman but it is taking a single number as a separate value. I am passing the array like `guides:"171"` and it is inserting like 1,7,1 how to solve this??

Comment: `"171"` isn't an array, it's a string. If you treat it like an array, you will get three separate values `"1"`,`"7"`, and `"1"`.

Comment: how can I get this as "171"

Comment: Don't loop through it, just insert `req.body.guides` once instead of `req.body.guides[i]` in a loop.

Comment: If I pass more than one value like ["171","169"] loop is required.

Comment: But you haven't, you said you passed a single value like `guides: "171"`

Comment: If you want to loop through an array, you should always pass an array in, but it can be an array with 1 or even 0 elements, like `guides: ["171"]` or `guides: []`. If you pass `guides: "171"` and loop through it, you are looping through a string and get the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: ok if we use for loop we cant get "171" as a single value??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162487/discussion-between-m-gowda-and-paulpro).